# How to query mongodb with query Builder in java?

Tags: java, mongodb, query-builder

I need to make a query in java to MongoDB, how could I do it with QueryBuilder, this is my query:

```
db.c_chm8_transactionality.aggregate([
   {
      "$match":{
         "$or":[
            {
               "$or":[
                  {
                     "gf_customer_id":"002168855"
                  },
                  {
                     "gf_customer_id":"009507458"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "$and":[
                  {
                     "gf_cutoff_date":{
                        "$gte":new Date(2000-08-07)
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "gf_cutoff_date":{
                        "$lte":new Date(2020-08-07)
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "$group":{
         "_id":{
            "gf_product_type_desc":"$gf_product_type_desc",
            "gf_channel_subtype_id":"$gf_channel_subtype_id",
            "gf_cutoff_date":"$gf_cutoff_date"
         },
         "transaccionTotal":{
            "$sum":"$gf_monthly_transactions_number"
         }
      }
   }
]);
```

By the way, if anyone knows where I can find documentation to make these queries, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [Refer this documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/java/sync/current/fundamentals/aggregation/#basic-aggregation-example4)

Create a `MongoCollection` object.
Create a `list` to have aggregate pipelines
`Aggregates` is a class where you will have all valid pipelines.
Pass the list to `aggregate` function of the `MongoCollection` object.